# Calculate the electric potential energy stored in a capacitor

Tags: energy, capacitance

Calculate the electric potential energy stored in a capacitor that stores 3.40 x 10^-10 C of charge at 20.0v

Comment: Can you provide your efforts to solve your question?

Answer (score 3):

Don't be scared, we are here to help.

$U = \frac{1}{2}QV$

Therefore,

$U = \frac{1}{2}3.4\times10^{-10}\times 20$

Therefore,

$U = 3.4 \times 10^{-9} J$

Comment: It is $\frac 12 CV^2$ and not $\frac 12 CV$

Comment: @SatwikPasani Depends on your definition of C I think.  I was using C for "charge" although you were probably using C for capacitance.  I changed C to Q to make it less ambiguous.

Comment: That's perfect. I guess the common convention is $C$ for capacitance and hence I was mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Energy stored in a capacitor= 0.5*charge stored* potential difference

=0.5*3.40 x 10^-10 *20.0

=3.4*10^-9 Joules